# How to use find with -delete when looking for directories

Tags: linux, find

I know I can do

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

But when I'm loooking for specific directories, `-delete` fails reporting that directories are not empty.

Is it possible to force find to delete non empty directories? I don't want to uses `-exec rm -rf '{}'` because it seems more mistake-prone to me.

Comment: My answer was not correct - deleted. I believe if you are looking for directories, the only real way to prune them is with "find . -type d -name 'directory*' -exec rm -rf '{}'" as you suggest.

Comment: find . -type d -name '*foo' -print | xargs rm -rf; If you are concerned with spaces in names pipe to ... | while read d; do rm -rf $d; done instead of xargs. If you know the directories are empty, use rmdir instead of rm -r

Answer (score 1):

```
find . \( -name '*.pyc' -o -path '*.pyc/*' \) -delete
```

If a directory matches `-name '*.pyc'` then everything inside matches `-path '*.pyc/*'`. And the other way around: if something matches `-path '*.pyc/*'` then there is a directory that matches `-name '*.pyc'` somewhere above it. We use logical OR (`-o`) to delete objects of either kind.

Notes:

- You need brackets because of this: [Why does `find` in Linux skip expected results when `-o` is used?](https://superuser.com/q/966227/432690)
- `-delete` implies `-depth`, so objects are deleted in the right order.
- Warning: `find . …` should work well but `find path …` may not. Consider

  ```
  find /mnt/a.pyc/foo/ \( -name '*.pyc' -o -path '*.pyc/*' \) -delete
  ```

  The `-path '*.pyc/*'` will match *everything* while `-name '*.pyc'` may match nothing. In this case the command will delete more than you expect.
- [`-delete` is not required by POSIX](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690). Portable solution needs `-exec rm …` or `xargs`. I don't know what you mean by "more mistake-prone". Your `-exec rm -rf '{}'` seems almost fine. After adding `--` it seems completely fine to me:

  ```
  find . -name '*.pyc' -prune -exec rm -rf -- {} +
  ```

  I used `-prune` to avoid this scenario: [Delete files and directories by their names. No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115863/108618).