# Why does `find` in Linux skip expected results when `-o` is used?

Tags: linux, find

Why in Linux (Debian 8)

```
touch 1.cpp 1.h
find . -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -exec echo {} \;
```

outputs only `1.h` while

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h"
```

outputs both? Is it a bug or feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think once you used `-or` operator, then you've to keep it consistent in order to avoid ambiguous order of logical operations when you have multiple conditions connected using logical OR.

It seems the `-exec` part is grouped together with the second `-name "*.h"`.

So in order to make it work correctly, you've to add the brackets as below:

```
find . '(' -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' ')' -exec echo {} ';'
```

> <sup>Remember: The parentheses must be quoted or escaped with a backslash to prevent them from being interpreted as special shell characters.</sup>

Alternatively combine few extensions into one by using `-regex`:

```
find . ! -regex ".*\.\(cpp\|h\)" -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither. It's the syntax of the options that is "wrong". `find` evalutates sequencially. Hence, it evaluates the first expression (`-name "*.cpp"`) then encounters a `-o` flag. If the first expression is true, `find` will not continue evaluating the second one (`-name "*.h" -exec echo {} \;`), instead does nothing. You see, the whole part after `-o` is one expression. Therefore, this is only executed for files that match the second expression. That's why you see only the `1.h` file, which passes only the second expression. See the find manpage:

```
   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

**Why is this useful?** Consider the following:

```
find /path -exec test_file_for_something {} -print \; -o -name "xyz" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

In this find statement the file is given to `test_file_for_something` as a parameter. Now, depending on that commands return code the first expression is true (then `-print` is executed and it ends there) or false (then the second expression after the `-o` flag is evaluated). And if that one is true (the name is `xyz`), then `-exec` is executed.

For your problem you can instead use this to group the elements together as **one expression**:

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround your search criteria with brackets as such:

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the way find works with it's operators.

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/find section OPERATORS

> OPERATORS
>
> Listed in order of decreasing precedence: ( expr ) Force precedence.
>   Since parentheses are special to the shell, you will normally need to
>   quote them. Many of the examples in this manual page use backslashes
>   for this purpose: '(...)' instead of '(...)'. ! expr True if expr is
>   false. This character will also usually need protection from
>   interpretation by the shell.
>
> -not expr Same as ! expr, but not POSIX compliant. expr1 expr2 Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with an implied "and";
>   expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false. expr1 -a expr2 Same as expr1
>   expr2. expr1 -and expr2 Same as expr1 expr2, but not POSIX compliant.
>   expr1 -o expr2 Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true. expr1 -or
>   expr2 Same as expr1 -o expr2, but not POSIX compliant. expr1 , expr2
>   List; both expr1 and expr2 are always evaluated. The value of expr1 is
>   discarded; the value of the list is the value of expr2. The comma
>   operator can be useful for searching for several different types of
>   thing, but traversing the filesystem hierarchy only once. The -fprintf
>   action can be used to list the various matched items into several
>   different output files.

This should give you the result you want:

> find . \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec echo {} \;

Your command is doing this (command won't work, just to show you the logic):

> find . -name '*.cpp' (-o -name '*.h' -exec echo {} \;)