# How to remove files using find's multiple -name parameter?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, find, syntax

How to remove files, containing tilde in the filename or extension, recursively?

For example, files of the vim, with the names like `.my_file.c.un~`?

I'm using this find sequence for that:

```
find . -name "*.un~" -o -name "*.swo" -o -name "*.swp" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

But it doesn't remove the files. Still running just a pure `find` displaying a list of the files correctly:

```
./.my_file.c.un~
./.my_file.c.swp
./.file2.c.un~
```

Also, removing them with the pure `rm -f .my_file.c.un~` works perfectly. Changing the `-exec rm -f {} \;` into the `-delete` still doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use multiple logical operations, you need to group them by brackets as below:

```
find . \( -name "*.un~" -o -name "*.swo" -o -name "*.swp" \) -delete
```

where you have to either backslash or quote the brackets (`'(' ... ')'`) to avoid parsing these special characters by the shell.

In above example I'm using `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -f {}` which automatically remove the file, so you don't need to worry about files with spaces, otherwise it could end up [bad](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac) for you.

For more syntax examples, check `man find`.

See also:

- [Strange “find” behavior in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/966227/87805)
- [find(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) (*OPERATORS* section)