# Ubuntu find files and directory matching a name in one line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, find

There are parameters of `find` command for finding files and directories respectively `-f` and `-d`, but I want to avoid writing two `find` commands and `&&` or `||` between them.

I want to find file or directory(whichever is found conditionally) in one command, can `-d` and `-f` be ORed ?

Comment: Similar: [How to remove files using find's multiple -name parameter?](http://superuser.com/q/977317/87805)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` option.

> From the [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) man page (under the OPERATORS heading):
>
> ```
>    expr1 -o expr2
>           Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify `-f` nor `-d`, `find` with show you all types of inodes (files, directories, devices, link etc...). If you want files and directories only, then use `-o`, and possibly use escaped parenthesis if you are going to use other type of conditins.

For example, all files, directories, links etc.... which have been modified/created in the past 2 days:

`find . -iname '*blah*' -mtime -2`

Same as above, but files and directory exclusively (no sym links, devices...)

`find . -iname '*blah*' \( -type d -o -type f \) -mtime -2`