# Use multiple conditions in find regex in shell

Tags: shell, regex, find

EDITED: 
I need to use -E for extended regex.

I have a folder with this files (just an example):
[image: directory structure]

I'm trying to find all files that:

1. Start and end with `#`. (e.g `#hi.h#`)
2. End with `~`. (e.g `file.txt~`)

I can find 1 condition files or 2 condition files, but i can't combine both in one regex.

```
$ find . -regex "./.*~"
./lld~

$ find . -regex "./#.*#"
./#x2#
./#x#
```

But this command is not working:

```
$ find . -regex "./(.*~$)|(#.*#)"
```

What am I doing wrong? how I can combine these regexes?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -regex "\./#.*#\|\./.*~"
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use `-E` for extended regex.

Invoke `find . -regextype help` to learn available options. GNU `find` in my Debian supports few. This works:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./(.*~$|#.*#)'
```

Note I have debugged and simplified the regex a little (`\./.*~$|\./#.*#` would also work). Other options that work for me in this particular case: `posix-egrep`, `egrep`, `posix-awk`, `awk`, `gnu-awk`.

---

This command:

```
find . -regex '\./#.*#\|\./.*~'
```

where `|` is escaped works for me. Credits to [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1488790/432690). Proper escaping of `(` and `)` makes the following work as well:

```
find . -regex '\./\(.*~$\|#.*#\)'
```

without relying on extended regular expressions.

---

You don't have to compact the two expressions into one. If these work:

```
find . -regex '\./.*~'
find . -regex '\./#.*#'
```

then you can get files matching one regex or the other this way:

```
find . -regex '\./.*~' -o -regex '\./#.*#'
```

Be warned: [*Why does `find` in Linux skip expected results when `-o` is used?*](https://superuser.com/q/966227/432690) If you want to add more tests/actions before and/or after then you don't want this:

```
find . -test1 -test2 -regex '\./.*~' -o -regex '\./#.*#' -test3 …
```

but this:

```
find . -test1 -test2 '(' -regex '\./.*~' -o -regex '\./#.*#' ')' -test3 …
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Just a short remark: Whenever using a more powerful tool, like a regular expression type providing more features, one has to ask the price, which will always be paid with either computation time or memory. For this reason I prefer the simplest tool that does the trick. In this case that means to avoid the ```-regextype``` parameter, to gain a 1/3 real-time speedup.

Comment: `regextype` doesn't work on macOS