# Using regex groups with find

Tags: bash, regex, find

Given a list of files, I want to find all the ones ending with either `.pem` or `.cer`.  This command works to find the PEMs.

```
find . -d 1 -regex ".*\.pem"
```

But this command finds nothing:

```
find . -d 1 -regex ".*\.(pem|cer)"
```

This syntax works in the BBedit pattern playground.  Is there some way to use regex groups with find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use multiple conditions in find regex in shell](https://superuser.com/questions/1488718/use-multiple-conditions-in-find-regex-in-shell)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even use regexps for this, instead i would use:

`find . -name "*.pem" -o -name '*.cer'`

It might even be faster (although we are talking about fraction of seconds here) because  parsing regexps is more expensive in cputime.

**EDIT:**

Now that I see Hannu's comment, I notice (based on the command that you originally tried) that maybe you don't want to check subdirs. If this is the case then it becomes:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pem" -o -name '*.cer'`

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 2 -regex ".*\.rar" -or -regex ".*\.zip"` (to catch files in my Downloads dir ;-)

Comment: Good point, this is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

#### This command finds nothing:

```
find . -d 1 -regex ".*\.(pem|cer)"
```

You need to use `'` instead of `"` and escape `(` and `)` as follows:

```
find . -d 1 -regex '.*\.\(pem|cer\)'
```