# Why does 'find -o -print' produce no output?

Tags: bash, posix

I'm getting a result from the unix 'find' command that I don't understand.

Using the Terminal on MacOS, which I believe is a POSIX-compliant os, running this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "version 1" 
find . -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*foo"
#
echo "version 2" 
find . -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*foo" -print
```

I obtain the result:

```
version 1
./file1.tif
./file2.tif
./file3.tif
version 2
%
```

**I expected to get the same output.**  Why does "print" with "or" suppress the output and cause nothing to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

> ```
> find . -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*foo"
> ```

is equivalent to:

```
find . \( -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*foo" \) -print
```

In other words the implicit `-print` is not mindlessly added to the end. It is added to the end after treating the explicit expression as a whole. This is clearly stated in the [POSIX specification of `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> If no expression is present, `-print` shall be used as the expression. Otherwise, if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries `-exec`, `-ok`, or `-print`, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by:
>
> ```
> ( given_expression ) -print
> ```

In a shell you want to escape or quote each parenthesis, thus `\(` and `\)` in my code above. Also note your implementation of `find` may add something (e.g. `-printf`) to the list of primaries that suppress the implicit `-print`.

Your other command is:

> ```
> find . -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*foo" -print
> ```

and it is equivalent to:

```
find . -iname "*tif" -o \( -iname "*foo" -a -print \)
```

The placement of parentheses is an implication of the fact `-a` (even if you omit it) binds "stronger" than `-o`.

Now the following fragment of the manual is relevant:

> `expression  -o  expression`
> Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.

In our case the second expression is the whole content of the parentheses. If for a given file `-iname "*tif"` evaluates as true then `-iname "*foo" -a -print` is not evaluated at all.

A somewhat surprising consequence of this "at all" is manifested in the following command with two occurrences of `-iname "*tif"`:

```
find . -iname "*tif" -o -iname "*tif" -print
```

This command will never `-print`. For any file:

- either the first `-iname "*tif"` is true and then everything after `-o` is not evaluated;
- or the first `-iname "*tif"` is false and thus the second `-iname "*tif"` is evaluated and also false, so `-print` is not evaluated.

`find . expression1 -o expression2 -print` will `-print` a pathname if and only if `expression1` evaluates as false and `expression2` evaluates as true.

Similar question: [*Combining multiple find commands into one*](https://superuser.com/q/1387979/432690).

Comment: Thank you, that's very thorough and the explicit ```-a``` (and) is clear.  (I did think the print was mindlessly added at the end, like an if..then.) Is it correct that ```-exec``` has the same issue as ```-print```?

Comment: @whiskeychief AFAIK `-exec` is never implicitly added, but if *you* add it to the end then yes, [you will experience the "issue"](https://superuser.com/q/966227/432690).